# R: is there an equivalent to applying Excel's locked cell reference to an entire field's calculations?

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to migrate a simulation/calculator from Excel to R. However, I'm having trouble finding the R equivalents in Excel.

I eventually plan on having the simulation/calculator on either Rmarkdown or shiny.

For this issue, I'm trying to replicate calculating against a locked cell reference.

I have two separate tables.

**Table 1**

```
x   y   z
0.5 0.3 120
```

**Table 2**

```
a  b
32 33
7  22
65 11
43 21
3  45
```

Table 1 is designed for inputs to be changed frequently by the user. If this was shiny I suppose it would be the sliding scale.

For Table 2, I want to add a calculated field multiplying each "cell" by Table 1's x, which is 0.5.

If this was excel, I would add two $ signs to the cell to lock the cell reference. The equation would be `Table 2(C2) = Table 2(A2) * Table 1($X$2), Table 2(C3) = Table 2(A3) * Table 1($X$2)`.

The end goal is that the results in Table 2 are graphed in shiny.

In R, I have the following:

```
Table2$c <- Table2$a * Table1$x
```

However, I am getting an error. I'm not sure if it is because the table size must be the same. If that's the case, is there syntax to *lock* a calculation? For example if I just put

```
Table2$c <- Table2$a * 0.5
```

I don't think there would be an issue. But I want that 0.5 to be able to change dynamically. Do I need to make an interim step to transform Table 1 to the same size as Table 2 and reiterate x?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have any error. Could you share the error line?

Comment: You give so much info. But then all you say is "I am getting an error". Tell us what the error is! Show the code you ran and the output that you get.

Comment: Apologies, my error is: ``Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, c, value = numeric(0)) :    replacement has 0 rows, data has 5``.

Comment: Actually, I'm taking a second look and using Table1$y in place of x succeeded. Also, another table I had that's the same row size as Table 2 occasionally failed. I'm thinking something is very wrong with these csv files now.

Comment: Thank you for confirming Edo. There were formatting errors with the csv file I used. I manually created the data frame within the code. I had fewer errors but one was still ocurring (similar to my comment below Dason). It was because I named the variables incorrectly. After that, everything works. Looks like the concept of locked cell references ($A$1) is embedded in R. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to multiply two vectors in R (a column in a dataframe is a vector) they need to be the same size. However, like you said, it is also possible to multiply a vector with a single number. If Table1 always has only one row this should work:

```
Table1 <- data.frame(x = 0.5,
                     y = 0.3,
                     z = 120)

Table2 <- data.frame(a = c(32, 7, 65, 43, 3),
                     b = c(33, 22, 11, 21, 45))


> Table2$a * Table1$x
[1] 16.0  3.5 32.5 21.5  1.5
```

The fact that you get an error might mean there something wrong with Table1?

Comment: Thank you. Your hunch was right. There were formatting errors with the csv file I used. I manually created the data frame within the code. I had fewer errors but one was still ocurring (similar to my comment below Dason). It was because I named the variables incorrectly. After that, everything works. Looks like the concept of locked cell references ($A$1) is embedded in R. Thanks!